# A distribution that returns only a single floating point value in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have some simulation code that draws from various distributions. To facilitate some sanity checks, is there a way to make a `Distribution` that returns only a single floating-point value? That way I can test without changing code that calls `rand` on the distribution. Right now I'm doing something like, supposing I want to always get the value `2.2`

```
mydist = Normal(2.2, 0.000001)
```

But this seems kind of silly. Of course, if I change the variance to `0` I get an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Distibutions.jl` docs have an [extends](https://juliastats.github.io/Distributions.jl/latest/extends.html) section, so you can see what needs to be defined. An incomplete implementation of a new `Distribution` starts

```
using Distributions
struct OneFloatDistribution <: Distribution{Univariate,Continuous}
    v::Float64
end
Base.rand(x::OneFloatDistribution) = x.v
```

You can get down to two possible floating point numbers with `Uniform(1.0,nextfloat(1.0))`

Comment: Thanks. You say this implementation is incomplete, but it seems to work for me as is based on a quick test...anything I should be cautious about?

Comment: You should be cautious about using any functionality of the `Distribution` type other than sampling from it. Eg the `cdf` and `pdf` are unavailable, so anything depending on that will fail. But you should get method errors, so just add methods as you need them.